# SQL Count in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find items that have shown up one time or less on a report. I know that to find how many times each item has apepared, I use this.

```
select COUNT(VP.VendorPartID)
from Purchasing.PurchaseOrder PO with (nolock)
    inner join dbo.tblVendor V with (nolock)
        on PO.VendorID=V.VendorID
    inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderItem POI with (nolock)
        on PO.PurchaseOrderID=POI.PurchaseOrderID
    inner join Purchasing.VendorPart VP with (nolock)
        on POI.VendorPartID=VP.VendorPartID
where V.ProductTypeID=4
group by PO.PurchaseOrderID
```

But I tried to nest it within another query to be able to set that it must appear 1 time or less, and it says there's an error because

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression."

I did this, which I'm guessing is likely pretty wrong, haha.

```
select VP.VendorPartID,VP.VendorPartDescription
from Purchasing.PurchaseOrder PO with (nolock)
    inner join dbo.tblVendor V with (nolock)
        on PO.VendorID=V.VendorID
    inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderItem POI with (nolock)
        on PO.PurchaseOrderID=POI.PurchaseOrderID
    inner join Purchasing.VendorPart VP with (nolock)
        on POI.VendorPartID=VP.VendorPartID
where (
        select COUNT(VP.VendorPartID)
        from Purchasing.PurchaseOrder PO with (nolock)
            inner join dbo.tblVendor V with (nolock)
                on PO.VendorID=V.VendorID
            inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderItem POI with (nolock)
                on PO.PurchaseOrderID=POI.PurchaseOrderID
            inner join Purchasing.VendorPart VP with (nolock)
                on POI.VendorPartID=VP.VendorPartID
        where V.ProductTypeID=4
        group by PO.PurchaseOrderID
        ) < 2
group by VP.VendorPartID,VP.VendorPartDescription
```

Desired results would be

```
VendorPartID  VendorPartDescription  
001           name 1                 
002           name 2                 
003           name 3
```

It would show only those that had appeared 1 time on the purchase orders.

Comment: Why are you grouping by PurchaseOrderID? Do you want one total count or do you want a count per PurchaseOrderID? If the subquery returns a row per PurchaseOrderID, you can't compare a set to a number. Can you show some sample data and desired results? I've looked over your query multiple times and I can't reverse engineer it. Is the type filter only supposed to be in the subquery? Why?

Comment: Try looking into the HAVING clause...

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I want items to count the times they appear on the purchase order so I can see which ones have only appeared once or less.

Comment: Show sample data and desired results. Word problems are hard.

Answer (score 3):

The `HAVING` clause is what you need--it's like a `WHERE` clause, but applied to a `GROUP BY`

Something to the effect of:

```
Select Id, count(othercolumn)
from sometable
where somecolumn = something
group by Id
having (count(somecolumn) < 2)
```

Comment: Nice and clean.  Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

If this really works for your count:

```
select COUNT(VP.VendorPartID)
from Purchasing.PurchaseOrder PO with (nolock)
    inner join dbo.tblVendor V with (nolock)
        on PO.VendorID=V.VendorID
    inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderItem POI with (nolock)
        on PO.PurchaseOrderID=POI.PurchaseOrderID
    inner join Purchasing.VendorPart VP with (nolock)
        on POI.VendorPartID=VP.VendorPartID
where V.ProductTypeID=4
group by PO.PurchaseOrderID`
```

Then simply add a [`having`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) clause:

```
select PO.PurchaseOrderID, COUNT(VP.VendorPartID)
from Purchasing.PurchaseOrder PO with (nolock)
    inner join dbo.tblVendor V with (nolock)
        on PO.VendorID=V.VendorID
    inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderItem POI with (nolock)
        on PO.PurchaseOrderID=POI.PurchaseOrderID
    inner join Purchasing.VendorPart VP with (nolock)
        on POI.VendorPartID=VP.VendorPartID
where V.ProductTypeID=4
group by PO.PurchaseOrderID
having COUNT(VP.VendorPartID) <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this which allows you to get the details based on the count

```
select * from
(select VP.VendorPartID,VP.VendorPartDescription,COUNT(VP.VendorPartID) as PartCount
  from Purchasing.PurchaseOrder PO with (nolock)
    inner join dbo.tblVendor V with (nolock)
      on PO.VendorID=V.VendorID
    inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderItem POI with (nolock)
      on PO.PurchaseOrderID=POI.PurchaseOrderID
    inner join Purchasing.VendorPart VP with (nolock)
      on POI.VendorPartID=VP.VendorPartID
group by
  VP.VendorPartID,VP.VendorPartDescription) as qCounts
where qCounts.PartCount < 2
```